# Dokcer Compose - MYSQL and WORDPRESS: MySQL Connection Error:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I just can't understand the behavior of the connection between MYSQL and WORDPRESS. I thought, the value of the variables WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD and MYSQL_PASSWORD should be a match. Furthermore, I get a connection error when I run docker-compose with the following yaml (value of the wordpress_db_password and mysql_password are the same):

```
version:  '3.3'
services: 
    mysql_database: 
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes: 
            - mysql_database_volume:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_database
            MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword
    wordpress: 
        depends_on:
            - mysql_database
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql_database:3306 
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: somepassword
volumes: 
    mysql_database_volume:
```

But it works when I just change the value of wordpress_db_password to "wordpress". What am I missing here? It just works here with this value. Any idea?

```
version:  '3.3'
services: 
    mysql_database: 
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes: 
            - mysql_database_volume:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_database
            MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword
    wordpress: 
        depends_on:
            - mysql_database
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql_database:3306 
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes: 
    mysql_database_volume:
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related. It appears to be more suitable for [wordpress.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example did not work for me. But I took your first example and added a a wordpress `environment` variable `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_database` and it works. Wordpress just did not have the database name. For reference I looked at [Quickstart: Compose and WordPress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) Docker documentation.

If you still have problems try stopping and removing your containers and removing the volume. You can get the container IDs with `docker ps -a` and then `docker stop /ID/ && docker rm /ID/`. And for the volume ID `docker volume ls` and then `docker volume rm /ID/`.

Also, I would like to note that when starting up, wordpress will log multiple "MySQL Connection Error" errors until the database ready.